# Getting content of another website into my windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, emulation

I used httpwebrequest to get content from another website into my windows phone application as below. i wanted to get the html of a page and then parse it to get my desired data.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request); 
        }

        private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
      HttpWebResponse myResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);// Exception is showing here.

            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                //TextBlockResults.Text = results; //-- on another thread!
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TextBlockResults.Text = results);
            }
            myResponse.Close();
        }
```

But getting the following error:

> {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException:  The remote server returned an
>   error: NotFound.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object
>   sendState)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at myApplication.MainPage.RespCallback(IAsyncResult
>   asynchronousResult)}

What might be the problem? any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (WebClient):

```
public void Client(string uri)
{
    var clientToken = new WebClient();
    clientToken.OpenReadCompleted += clientToken_OpenReadCompleted;
    clientToken.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri));
}

private void clientToken_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
       Stream reply = e.Result;
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(reply);

       MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Or read this post [Portable HttpClient for .NET Framework and Windows Phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx)

Comment: same error is showing 'The remote server returned an error: NotFound'. i have used the contoso url like clientToken.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.contoso.com")); url is: "http://www.contoso.com". looks like it is unable to access the service of the url

Comment: www.contoso.com - is sites Microsoft. Try clientToken.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("www.microsoft.com"));

Comment: thanks for your quick ans. but if try with www.microsoft.com then url format gives error. if i append http:// to the url then the same error appears. Is there any setting needed for the emulator?